# Related Object Does Not Exist at /account_settings/

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-errors

Here is the code of my project that contains the files models.py,
views.py and urls.py. It showing me the error that object does not
exist. `Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist`
`Exception Value: User has no student`.

Now where have I made a mistake? I'm a newbie. I searched a lot but unable to  resolve it.

```
# Create your models here.
            
            class School(models.Model):
                schoolid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
                schoolname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null= True)
              #  schoolimage = models.ImageField()
                schoolcontactno = models.CharField(max_length=13, null= 
        True)
                schooladdress = models.CharField(max_length=500)
                createddate = models.DateTimeField(null= True)
                schoolemail = models.EmailField(null= True)
                password = models.CharField(max_length=13,null= True)
            
                def __str__(self):
                    return self.schoolname
            
            class Section(models.Model):
                sectionid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
                sectionname = models.CharField(max_length=500,null= True)
                schoolid = models.ForeignKey(School,null= 
        True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
            
            
            class Status(models.Model):
                statusid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
                statustype = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
            
            class Client(models.Model):
                userid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
                username = models.CharField(max_length=50,null = True)
                ceratedon = models.DateTimeField(null = True)
                email = models.CharField(max_length=50,null = True)
                password = models.CharField(max_length=13)
                certificatetypename = models.CharField(max_length=100,null 
        = True)
                cnic = models.CharField(max_length=50,null = True)
                contactnumber = models.CharField(max_length=13,null = True)
             #   image = models.CharField(max_length='',null = True)
                status = models.ForeignKey(Status, 
        null=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
                confirmpassword = models.CharField(max_length=13,null = 
        True)
            
            class TblClass(models.Model):
                classid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
              #  name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null= True)
                schoolid = models.ForeignKey(School,null= 
        True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
            
            
            class RoleName(models.Model):
                roleid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
                rolename = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
            
            class Course(models.Model):
                courseid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
                coursedescription = models.CharField(max_length=500,null= 
        True)
                coursename = models.CharField(max_length=50,null= True)
                userid = models.ForeignKey(Client,null= 
        True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
                code = models.CharField(max_length=50,null= True)
                videolink = models.CharField(max_length=500 ,null= True)
                roleid = 
        models.ForeignKey(RoleName,null=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
                createddate = models.DateTimeField()
             #   imagelink = models.CharField(max_length='')
                duration = models.DateTimeField()
            #    longdes = models.CharField(max_length='')
                coursetype = models.CharField(max_length=50)
                classid = 
        models.ForeignKey(TblClass,null=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
             #   assignto = models.CharField(max_length='')
                status = models.BinaryField(null = True)
            
            class Day(models.Model):
                id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
                name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null =True)
            
            class Exam(models.Model):
                
                examid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
                examname = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)
            
            class SchoolAssignment(models.Model):
                assignmentid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
                assignmentname = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
                classid = 
        models.ForeignKey(TblClass,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
                courseid = models.ForeignKey(Course, 
        null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
                assignmenturl = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)
                duration = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
                schoolid = 
        models.ForeignKey(School,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
                createddate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
                userid = 
        models.ForeignKey(Client,null=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
            
            
            class TimeTable(models.Model):
                id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
                classid = 
        models.ForeignKey(TblClass,null=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
                courseid = 
        models.ForeignKey(Course,null=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
                sectionid = 
        models.ForeignKey(Section,null=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
                starttime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
                endtime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
                allocationstatus = 
        models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
                dayid = 
        models.ForeignKey(Day,null=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
                schoolid = 
        models.ForeignKey(School,null=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
            
            
            class Student(models.Model):
                user = models.OneToOneField(User,null 
        =True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
                
                id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
                sname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
                phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
                email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
                date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, 
        null=True)
                regno = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
                registrationdate = models.DateTimeField(null =True)
                address = models.CharField(max_length=100,null =True)
               # classid = models.ForeignKey(TblClass,null=True, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
               # schoolid = models.ForeignKey(School,null=True, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
               # sectionid = models.ForeignKey(Section,null=True, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
                std_profile = models.ImageField(default="download.png", 
        null = True,blank = True)
            
                
                def __str__(self):
                    return self.sname
            class StudentResult(models.Model):
                studentresultid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
                studentid = models.ForeignKey(Student,null 
        =True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
                courseid = 
        models.ForeignKey(Course,null=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
                totalmarks = models.IntegerField(null = True)
                marksobtained = models.IntegerField(null = True)
                percentage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, 
        decimal_places=2,null = True)
                schoolid = models.ForeignKey(School,null = 
        True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
                classid = models.ForeignKey(TblClass,null = 
        True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
                createddate = models.DateTimeField(null = True)
                sectionid = 
        models.ForeignKey(Section,null=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
                examid = 
        models.ForeignKey(Exam,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
            
            class SubmitAssignment(models.Model):
                uploadid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
                assignmentid = models.ForeignKey(SchoolAssignment, 
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
                schoolid = 
        models.ForeignKey(School,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null = True)
                studentid = models.ForeignKey(Student, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null = True)
                courseid = models.ForeignKey(Course, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null = True)
                uploadurl = models.CharField(max_length=500,null = True)
                createddate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null = 
        True)
            
            
            class StudentHistory(models.Model):
                studenthistoryid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
                studentid = models.ForeignKey(Student,null=True, 
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
                lastclass = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
                createddate = 
        models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
                lastclasssection = 
        models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
            
                def __str__(self):
                    return self.studentid
        
        # Create your views here.
        @login_required(login_url='loginPage')
        def home(request):
            return render(request,'home.html')
        
        @unauthenticated_user
        def register(request):
        
            form = CreateUserForm()
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    user = form.save()
                    username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                    
                    group = Group.objects.get(name = 'student')
                    user.groups.add(group)
                    messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + 
        username)          
                    return redirect('loginPage')
                                
            context = {'form':form}
            return render(request, 'register.html', context)
        
        @unauthenticated_user
        def loginPage(request):
            if request.method == 'POST':
                username = request.POST.get('username')
                password =request.POST.get('password')
                user = authenticate(request, username=username, 
        password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('userpage')
                else:
                    messages.info(request, 'Username OR password is 
        incorrect')
            context = {}
            return render(request, 'login.html', context)
        
        def logoutUser(request):
            logout(request)
            return redirect('loginPage')
        
        
        @login_required(login_url='loginPage')
        def about(request):
            return render(request,'about.html')
        
        @login_required(login_url='loginPage')
        def contact(request):
            return render(request,'home.html')
        
        
        @login_required(login_url='loginPage')
        @allowed_users(allowed_roles=['student'])
        def userPage(request):
            return render(request, 'user.html')
        
        @login_required(login_url='loginPage')
        @allowed_users(allowed_roles=['student'])
        def account_settings(request):
            student = request.user.student
            form = StudentForm(instance=student)
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = StudentForm(request.POST, 
        request.FILES,instance=student)
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                    
                    
            context = {'form':form}
            return render(request, 'account_settings.html', context)
        
        @login_required(login_url='loginPage')
        @allowed_users(allowed_roles=['student'])
        def assignments(request):
            student = request.user.student
            form = StudentForm(instance=student)
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = StudentForm(request.POST, 
        request.FILES,instance=student)
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                    
                    
            context = {'form':form}
            return redirect(request,'assignment.html',context)
            """it is urls of the code"""
        urlpatterns = [
        path("", views.home, name = 'home'),
        path("register/", views.register, name = 'register'),
        path("about/", views.about, name = 'about'),
        path("contact/", views.contact, name = 'contact'),
        path("login/", views.loginPage, name = 'loginPage'),
        path("logout/", views.logoutUser, name = 'logout'),
        path("userpage/", views.userPage, name = 'userpage'),
        path("account_settings/", views.account_settings, name = 
        'account_settings'),
        path("assignments/", views.assignments, name = 'assignments'),
        
        ]'''
```

Comment: can you provide full error?

Answer (score 0):

In your view functions: *assignment* and *account_settings* you have this line.

```
            student = request.user.student
```

I believe what the error is saying, is that you haven't created any StudentObject for this User yet. Looking at your registration view, I don't see you are creating one here too. Am I correct? In case every USER should have a STUDENT object, you could add one upon registration like this and fill out all the blank fields later.

```
@unauthenticated_user
def register(request):

    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')

############################
            newstudent = Student(user=request.user)
            newstudent.save()
############################
     
            group = Group.objects.get(name = 'student')
            user.groups.add(group)
            messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + 
username)          
            return redirect('loginPage')
                        
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```